# Show if $\{(x, f(x)) : x \in X \}$ is closed then $f(X)$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis

I have to show the following

> Show if $\{(x, f(x)) : x \in X  \subset \mathbb{R} \}$  is closed then $f(X)$ is closed.

where $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

---

**Try**

To utilize the sequential closedness, for any $\langle f(x_n)\rangle \subset f(X)$  with $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = y_0$, I try to show $y_0 \in f(X)$. But since I'm not sure if $x_n$ converges, I cannot proceed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't prove it because it is not true. Take $X=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ and $f(x)=\frac1x$. Then $\left\{\bigl(x,f(x)\bigr)\,\middle|\,x\in X\right\}$ is closed, but $f(X)=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, which is not a closed subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thx for the beautiful counterexample. But just one more question : is my statement true when $f$ is bounded?

Comment: @Moreblue Take $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 + 1}$ for example.

Comment: No. Consider$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\frac1{1+x^2}.\end{array}$$Then $f(\mathbb R)=(0,1]$.

Comment: +1@JoséCarlosSantos sir Im not getting why  is $ \{(x,f(x))|x\in X \}$  closed ? My thinking : the limit $(0,0) \notin  \{(x,f(x))|x\in X \} \implies \{(x,f(x))|x\in X \}$ is **not** closed

Comment: If $f$ was a function such that $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$, then we would have $\lim_{x\to0}\bigl(x,f(x)\bigr)=(0,0)$ and it would follow that $\left\{\bigl(x,f(x)\bigr)\,\middle|\,x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\right\}$ is not closed. But, in fact, the limit $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ does not exist, and therefore you cannot deduce that $\left\{\bigl(x,f(x)\bigr)\,\middle|\,x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\right\}$ is not closed.

Comment: okay sir @JoséCarlosSantos But  you  didn't tag me .That's why I didn't get the notification .  Just read it now.

Comment: @jasmine Oops! Sorry about that.